# how to print object data with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, input

```
userInput = input("Enter Name: ")

class person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job

People = [
    person('Josh',23,'Consultant'),
    person('Maya',25,'Accountant'),
    person('Dan',32,'Social Worker'),
    person('Keon',38,'Biomaterials Developer'),
    person('Michelle',28,'Surgeon'),
    person('Joey',34,'Lawyer')
]
```

so if userInput = Josh, it would print Josh's name, age, and job

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: Iterate over the `People` list, looking at each `person` object.  If the current person has a name equal to the user input, print that person object.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow method is to iterate over the list and find a match.

```
def find_person(people, name):
    for person in people:
        if person.name == name:
            return person
    raise ValueError("No matching person found")
```

This is `O(n)` in the size of the list, which will cause problems if your list of people is large.

But since you know in advance that you're going to be looking up people by name, you can use the person's name as a dictionary key, effectively *indexing* by the name rather than an integer value. So rather than creating a list of people, creating a dictionary

```
people = {
    'Josh': person('Josh',23,'Consultant'),
    'Maya': person('Maya',25,'Accountant'),
    'Dan': person('Dan',32,'Social Worker'),
    'Keon': person('Keon',38,'Biomaterials Developer'),
    'Michelle': person('Michelle',28,'Surgeon'),
    'Joey': person('Joey',34,'Lawyer'),
}
```

Then "look up a person by name" is as simple as `people[name]`. Of course, you'll want to hide this complexity behind a class or something and make the client-facing side *look* like a list, or whatever data structure you want it to look like. This approach also currently assumes that no two people will ever have the same first name, though you can work around that by having a dictionary of lists if there's a possibility of duplicates.

Comment: i wrote
userInput = input("Enter Name: ")

class person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job

people = {
    'Josh': person('Josh',23,'Consultant'),
    'Maya': person('Maya',25,'Accountant'),
    'Dan': person('Dan',32,'Social Worker'),
    'Keon': person('Keon',38,'Biomaterials Developer'),
    'Michelle': person('Michelle',28,'Surgeon'),
    'Joey': person('Joey',34,'Lawyer'),
}

print(people[userInput])

but it returned "<__main__.person object at 0x000001F2E733BFD0>"

Comment: You haven't written a `__str__` or `__repr__` for your class, so you get the default representation using angled brackets and the class name. If you want something else printed, you need to print that thing or teach Python how to stringify your class.